# Clipping only one entry of a shapefile's attribute table using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

ArcGIS Pro user here struggling with a basic task. Is it possible to clip only one entry from a shapefile's attribute table to isolate the information and more important the polygon shape?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the short [Tour]. We use a Focused question/Best answer model here. "Is it possible" questions generally aren't asking the right question (since the answer is almost always "Yes", and it doesn't help). In most cases the answer is "Sure, lots of different ways; what have you tried, and where are you stuck?" which means the Question is lacking detail which would allow it to be answered. Please [Edit] your Question to contain a problem to be solved.

Answer (score 3):

Select the record, right-click in content and export (Data -> Export Features) should  export only the selected record(s) to the new feature class.

Answer (score 2):

Once you selected the feature(s) you are interested in, you can use the tool "copy features". It will only make a copy of the selected feature(s).